# How to correct stretched image on ext. widescreen monitor?

Tags: display, widescreen

I have my 13" laptop connected via VGA to a 23" ext. monitor but I noticed that images are slightly squashed/stretched out horizontally. (i.e. circles slightly look like ovals [X > Y])

My laptop resolution is 1280 x 800 at 60 Hz (GMA 950) while it's outputting 1680 x 1050 at 60 Hz on my ext. monitor

I've configured the GMA utility to maintain aspect ratio on both displays and the ext. monitor is set to 16:9.

Is there any way to correct the image so it doesn't look squashed/stretched out on the ext. monitor?

Answer (score 2):

> the ext. monitor is set to 16:9.

1280x800 and 1680x1050 are both 16:10

- 1280÷16 = 800÷10 = 80
- 1680÷16 = 1050÷10 = 105

Comment: i.e. the external monitor is set to the wrong resolution/ratio

Answer (score -1):

For no reason, mods decided to delete OP **own** reply and solution, so reposting.

TL;DR he ended up using a driver with [modded DTD](https://web.archive.org/web/20160330043114/http://www.komku.org/2009/10/how-to-get-1920x1080-full-hd-resolution.html) in order to finally be able to "see" the full 1080p resolution of his monitor.

This may have been due to some OEMs [specifically](https://web.archive.org/web/20100404053242/http://www.avsforum.com/avs-vb/showthread.php?t=947830) blacklisting a selected few in the BIOS, even though the [hardware](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/mobile-945-express-chipset-datasheet.pdf#page=376) should definitively support them. Or perhaps it may have been a [driver bug](https://web.archive.org/web/20191220220239/https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/user-community-for-visual-computing/topic/305322?page=2#comment-1534819), and a normal [custom mode](https://web.archive.org/web/20080913214655/http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-029478.htm) could have been already enough.